# get generic superclass of generic parameter

Tags: java, reflection

```
class Super<T> {}

class Child<A, B> extends Super<B> {}

class Code {
  public void method(Child<String, Integer> child) {}
}
```

I can use reflection to get the parameter type:

```
ParameterizedType ptype = (ParameterizedType) Code.class.getMethod("method").getGenericParameterTypes()[0]
```

But how can I get the generic superclass of ptype (meaning, not only `Super.class`, but also the type parameter `Integer`)

My use case is that I want to use reflection to determine if one of the arguments of a method is a Collection of MyClass objects (I don't have an actual argument instance to check)

Comment: Can you clarify your question a little bit more. I'm bit of lost in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type parameters are erased in java during compilation. Look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) or [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens). So you probably  will not able to do this.

Comment: if List<T> extends Collection<T>, and a parameter is of generic type List<String> (that is, getRawType returns List.class and getActualTypeArguments returns [String.class]), then the JVM conceptually has all knowledge to know the parameter is also Collection<String>. It is a matter of the reflection information, not type erasure (to know that the first generic parameter of List is also the first of Collection). But I guess there isn't one

Answer (score 1):

Well, from the example above you can do it. Because you can extract the actual type of the second type parameter (Integer) of the method parameter (Child).

```
Method method = Code.class.getMethod("method", Child.class);
ParameterizedType parameterType = (ParameterizedType) method.getGenericParameterTypes()[0];
Type secondType = parameterType.getActualTypeArguments()[1];
System.out.println(secondType == Integer.class);
```

Returns `true`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you cannot do it.

You can extract type parameters of `Child` (`String` and `Integer`) using `getActualTypeArguments()`, but you cannot correlate them with `T` in `Super<T>`.

Also you can extract `T` from `class Child extends Super<Integer>`, but it's not your case.

It means that if you want to find `Collection<MyClass>` in arguments you can only do it if you have `method(Collection<MyClass>)`, but not `method(ArrayList<MyClass>)` or something else.